# Set datasource to JPA without a container

Tags: java, eclipselink, jndi, jpa-2.1

I would like to use a a while testing my entities a special datasource

https://code.google.com/p/datasource-proxy/

which wraps the original datasource (in my case apache derby's) ClientDataSource

So how can i inject the datasource in my JPA without having a container...?

I tried to use simple-jndi but does not work. (not with eclipse link implementation of JPA2)

Is there a way to bypass the JNDI for the datasource when configuring persistence unit ?

(programatically ?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way for EclipseLink JPA implementation

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.PersistenceUnitProperties;
//define your datasource before proxyDS - not shown here
//then add this property to entity manager factory prop map

emfProps.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.NON_JTA_DATASOURCE, proxyDS);
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CompanyPU", emfProps);
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

I still want to find a more generic way for any JPA provider

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up the dataSource by program without using a container or JNDI lookup, then you can use the following way which contains Apache Derby's [ClientDataSource](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/publishedapi/org/apache/derby/jdbc/ClientDataSource.html):

```
public DataSource createDataSource() {
   ClientDataSource dataSource = new ClientDataSource();
   dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
   dataSource.setPortNumber(1527);
   dataSource.setDatabaseName("mytestdb");
   dataSource.setUser("myusername");
   dataSource.setPassword("mypasswd");
   return dataSource;
}
```

Then you can put this code in your application to get JDBC Connection:

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection("myusername", "mypasswd");
```

Comment: That i know how to do thanks....the problem is how i attach this datasource to the persistence context where a jndi lookup is done.